# Datetimepicker only showing some parts of the picker function

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to get the datetimepicker working that can be found [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/)

I installed this package using bower and linked all the stylesheets / js files.

When I visit the page I can only see some parts of the the actual datepicker.
Here are some pictures to have a better look:
[image]
[image]

My links:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('tether/dist/js/tether.min.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/moment.min.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}" defer></script>

<!-- Styles -->

<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

My HTML:

```
@extends ('layouts.app')

@section ('content')
<div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
@endsection
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the format:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/dd/YYYY'
});
```

According to the documentation, the format specified in the options defines what components are shown.

Comment: This works for getting the picker to open with the components, I'm still missing the glyphicons for some reason, I believe they should be included in the bootstrap css

Comment: @Dax You would need to open the code inspector and watch for your css resources, so you can check if glyphicons are being actually requested, remember that you need the 4 font files that are on the .zip file when you download boostrap from it's homepage: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @Dax But if you'd like, you can always use font awesome icons using this link tag

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">`

And then using a calendar icon like this:
`<i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>` instead of your `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>`

Comment: Yeah I figured that out , but the date picker itself has other icons, and those ones are also missing. I'm not getting any request for the icons

Comment: @Dax If you can't find the problem, then I would suggest you require your bootstrap files from a cdn source:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">`

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`